# regex: getting backreference to number, adding to it

Tags: python, regex, backreference

Simple regex question:

I want to replace page numbers in a string with pagenumber + some number (say, 10). I figured I could capture a matched page number with a backreference, do an operation on it and use it as the replacement argument in `re.sub`.

This works (just passing the value):

```
def add_pages(x):
    return x

re.sub("(?<=Page )(\d{2})",add_pages(r"\1") ,'here is Page 11 and here is Page 78\nthen there is Page 65',re.MULTILINE)
```

Yielding, of course,
`'here is Page 11 and here is Page 78\nthen there is Page 65'`

Now, if I change the add_pages function to modify the passed backreference, I get an error.

```
def add_pages(x):
        return int(x)+10


re.sub("(?<=Page )(\d{2})",add_pages(r"\1") ,'here is Page 11 and here is Page 78\nthen there is Page 65',re.MULTILINE)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\\1'
```

, as what is passed to the add_pages function seems to be the literal backreference, not what it references.

Absent extracting all matched numbers to a list and then processing and adding back, how would I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual problem is, you are supposed to pass a function to the second parameter of `re.sub`, instead you are calling a function and passing the return value.

#### Why does it work in the first case?

Whenever a match is found, the second parameter will be looked at. If it is a string, then it will be used as the replacement, if it is a function, then the function will be called with the [match object.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) In your case, `add_pages(r"\1")`, is simply returning `r"\1"` itself. So, the `re.sub` translates to this

```
print re.sub("(?<=Page )(\d{2})", r"\1", ...)
```

So, it actually replaces the original matched string with the same. That is why it works.

#### Why it doesn't work in the second case?

But, in the second case, when you do

```
add_pages(r"\1")
```

you are trying to convert `r"\1"` to an integer, which is not possible. That is why it is failing.

#### How to fix this?

The actual way to write this would be,

```
def add_pages(matchObject):
    return str(int(matchObject.group()) + 10)
print re.sub("(?<=Page )(\d{2})", add_pages, ...)
```

Read more about the `group` function, [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group)

Comment: Great explanation. As an add-on, could I expand to search not just for 2-digit page numbers and still keep the assertion here?

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Right now I match two-digit numbers with \d{2}. In the actual, non-toy example, I may have 3-digit numbers, too. Variable length patterns cause me trouble.

Comment: @ako You can change it to `\d{2,3}`, so that it will match either two or three digits

Comment: indeed, tried that one earlier but failed to match digits in the range. I had left the multiline flag on which seemed to be an issue. Turned it off and the repeater worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
def add_pages(matchobj):
    return str(int(matchobj.group(0))+10)


print re.sub("(?<=Page )(\d{2})",add_pages ,'here is Page 11 and here is Page 78\nthen there is Page 65',re.MULTILINE
```

Comment: Touch crowd here, it seems.