# Replacing a captured group in re.sub before converting to integer

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a series of regular expressions inside of a dictionary, where I iterate through each of the regexs and use re.sub on a specific string. For one of the regular expressions, I'm trying to find an integer 'i' followed by an arbitrary string, then a pipe, then another string, then a pipe. I want to replace this entire string with the string that is contained between the pipes, repeated 'i' times.

For example, it would convert the string `| "2" (arbitary string) | B |` into `| B || B |`, and the string `| 4 alsfjas;ldfkjasfl | foo |` into `| foo || foo || foo || foo |`

The current regex looks like this:

```
regexs = {
...
r"\"?(\d+?)\"?.*?\|(.*?)\|": r"\|\g<2>\|" * int(r"\g<1>"),
...
}
```

which would be called using

```
for regex in regexs:
    line = re.sub(regex, regexs[regex], line)
```

for some string 'line'.
The integer might be surrounded by quotation marks, which I ignore.

The problem I'm having is that python is trying to convert the string literal r"\g<1>" to an integer and then replace it with the captured group, whereas I want to first replace the captured group and then convert to an integer.

The error I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./regexTesting/testing.py", line 61, in <module>
    main()
  Fir"\"?(\d+?)\"?.*?\|(.*?)\|": r"\|\g<2>\|" * int(r"\g<1>"),
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\\g<1>'
```

Ultimately, I want to change the precedence of operations so that the regex replacing occurs before converting to an integer. How would I do this? If I can't change this precedence, is there another way I could get the results that I want using only regular expression syntax?

Comment: To manipulate a backreference value, you would need a lambda expression, or a callback method.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew a lambda expression to replace the backreference, or a lambda to convert to an integer?

Comment: The point is that you should get a match first, then you may cast the group value to an int. Casting `\g<1>` string to an int makes no sense.

Comment: Found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27143233/regex-getting-backreference-to-number-adding-to-it